# Database Back Up using Powershell

Tags: database, powershell, database-backups

I am trtying to take back up using poweshell 
Below is the command which we are trying to execute,

```
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "SERVER\DEFAULT" -Database "AFC" -BackupFile "\\REMOTESERVER\temp123\$dbName.bak"
```

However when we are trying to execute the same we are getting below error

> Backup-SqlDatabase : Failed to connect to server 10.254.5.37\DEFAULT.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "10.254.5.37\DEFAULT" -Database "A ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Backup-SqlDatabase], ConnectionFailureException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionFailureException,Microsoft.SqlServer.Man
>   agement.PowerShell.BackupSqlDatabaseCommand

However when we are trying to execute Get-ChildItem command we are gettting names of all databases.
Please help us.

Regards,
Pradeep

Comment: Does it work if you remove the backup backupfile param?

Comment: no, it is not working even after removing backupfile param, command which is I have executed is 

I am trtying to take back up using poweshell Below is the command which we are trying to execute,

Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "SERVER\DEFAULT" -Database "AFC"

Comment: Most likely, `10.254.5.37\DEFAULT` is not a registered service principal name (SPN) for your SQL Server.  You may need to use the hostname or fully-qualified hostname in order to connect to the SQL Server.  You can use `setspn.exe hostname -L` in order to see the registered SPNs of your SQL Server.  For assistance with reviewing, verifying, and configuring SPNs for your SQL Server, check-out Microsoft's Kerberos Configuration Manager for SQL Server.